# WebView - Error al cargar algunas Web's

Tags: java, android, webview

Cuando pongo este enlace:

http://www.writeurl.com/text/hc2m5gy29z0byqvo53ug/38nftxs4azvgifrbq6m9

Que es una web que te permite actualizar el texto online en mi aplicación sin tener que editar la App.

Pero siempre me da error: "We are trying to connect to the server." si uso por ejemplo Google si funciona y otras web's pero esa en concreto no, a qué se debe?
También me interesa otra opción para lo que quiero hacer.

Mi código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.prueba);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
        view.loadUrl("http://www.writeurl.com/text/hc2m5gy29z0byqvo53ug/38nftxs4azvgifrbq6m9"); 
        view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
    }

    private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
            view.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

Comment: cambia la url por [http://www.writeurl.com/new](http://www.writeurl.com/new)
que es la ruta que genera la url personalizada que no puedes replicar saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tu código es correcto!**, pero la página esta teniendo problemas en realidad, por esa razón te muestra el texto dentro del `WebView`.

Prueba con otra que puedas abrir en el browser y no tendrás problema.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No puedes compartir la página ya que esta genera un id de la sesión :

> hc2m5gy29z0byqvo53ug/38nftxs4azvgifrbq6m9

pero no puede ser compartida.

**Tienes que usar la url generada con la opción "Publish URL", ya que esta url si puede abrirse en una sesión distinta:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo raro es que llevo toda la tarde probando y desde el ordenador no he tenido ni una sola vez ese error, pero desde el WebView no ha funcionado ni una sola vez. Hay alguna otra web para hacer lo que quiero? O algún otro método que conozcas? Gracias @Elenasys !

Comment: Carga http://www.writeurl.com/ y el usuario deberá autenticarse, me parece que la página usa variables de sesión por eso no es valido el url que comentas.

Comment: Con http://www.writeurl.com/ funciona correctamente, pero claro no puedo ver mi texto, lo raro es que esa web no puedes registrarte ni nada, no hay solución entonces?

Comment: Tendrias que generar una página estatica donde muestres lo que deseas, en este caso, la página  genera un id de la sesión hc2m5gy29z0byqvo53ug/38nftxs4azvgifrbq6m9 pero no puede ser compartida.

Comment: Bueno finalmente lo he conseguido solucionar, para que funcione no vale con coger el enlace de Read, sino que tienes que usar el de "Publish URL" y cada vez que modifiques la información hay que volverle a dar para que el enlace siga funcionando y no caduque. Pero tu información me ha servido para encontrar la solución, Añade esto a la respuesta y la marco como Solución @Elenasys gracias de nuevo!

Comment: si la opción  "Publish URL" te da un url que se pueda abrir en cualquier dispositivo ese puede funcionar.

Comment: Así es, ponlo en la respuesta y lo marco como solución @Elenasys

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51468/discussion-between-elenasys-and-usernameyo).